# grunt cannot find module underscore

Tags: gruntjs, magento2

I followed the steps to install grunt (for Magento2), and when i try to do:

```
$grunt || sudo grunt

Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

When i must create the file Gruntfile.js i rename Gruntfile.js.sample

I tried:
- npm install
- npm install
- npm install node_modules

Anythink i forget?

(I doesn't found dev/tools/grunt/configs/theme.js but i have installed it in another server without it and nothing happends)